# Devices wake during sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

I have an M2 mac that continuously wakes devices while it is asleep. This results in my monitor constantly flickering back to life as it looses HDMI, goes into rest mode, then gets a flicker of signal, wakes, then goes back to sleep because there is no actual signal. I also see my Yubikey and logitech camera pulse periodically.

This is annoying more than a serious problem, but it does waste energy, I think drains some of my usb device batteries and keeps my home office awash in the semi glow of a big monitor.

I have:

- turned off wake on LAN to no effect.
- booted into safe mode and seen the same behavior
- tried systemically shutting off every conceivable application

The device is a work computer so it does have crowdstrike installed, but I don't know how I could disable that to test.

Thank you!

#### Update

Upon request from @ruskes here are samples of my pmset logs:

`pmset -g log | grep wake`

```
2023-12-21 14:57:48 -0800 Assertions            PID 521(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000085ff [System: PushSrvc SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-12-21 14:58:33 -0800 Assertions            PID 521(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:45  id:0x0xd000085ff [System: BGTask SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-12-21 14:59:58 -0800 Wake Requests         [process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1009 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:16:48 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.6Hours"] [*process=dasd request=TimerPlugin deltaSecs=925 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:15:24 info="com.apple.dasd:502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photosanalysis"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7199 wakeAt=2023-12-21 16:59:57 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=CSPNEvaluation deltaSecs=4572 wakeAt=2023-12-21 16:16:11] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=2881 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:48:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-invisible-com.apple.calaccessd.travelEngine.periodicRefreshTimer,1134"]           
2023-12-21 15:00:55 -0800 Assertions            PID 521(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00008d1e [System: PrevIdle PushSrvc SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-12-21 15:01:40 -0800 Assertions            PID 521(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:45  id:0x0xd00008d1e [System: BGTask SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-12-21 15:03:05 -0800 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=926 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:18:31 info="com.apple.dasd:502:com.apple.chronod.nextScheduledTimelineRefresh"] [process=dasd request=TimerPlugin deltaSecs=1072 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:20:57 info="com.apple.dasd:502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photos.ocr"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7199 wakeAt=2023-12-21 17:03:04 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=CSPNEvaluation deltaSecs=4385 wakeAt=2023-12-21 16:16:11] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=2694 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:48:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-invisible-com.apple.calaccessd.travelEngine.periodicRefreshTimer,1134"]           
2023-12-21 15:04:01 -0800 Assertions            PID 521(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000093f5 [System: PushSrvc SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-12-21 15:04:46 -0800 Assertions            PID 521(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:45  id:0x0xd000093f5 [System: BGTask SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-12-21 15:06:11 -0800 Wake Requests         [process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1064 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:23:56 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.2Hours"] [*process=dasd request=TimerPlugin deltaSecs=988 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:22:40 info="com.apple.dasd:502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photos.ocr"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2023-12-21 17:06:10 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=CSPNEvaluation deltaSecs=4199 wakeAt=2023-12-21 16:16:11] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=2508 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:48:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-invisible-com.apple.calaccessd.travelEngine.periodicRefreshTimer,1134"]           
2023-12-21 15:07:09 -0800 Assertions            PID 521(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd00009ae3 [System: PushSrvc SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-12-21 15:07:54 -0800 Assertions            PID 521(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.acwakelinger" 00:00:45  id:0x0xd00009ae3 [System: BGTask SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-12-21 15:48:00 -0800 Assertions            PID 521(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000a258 [System: BGTask SRPrevSleep kCPU]          
2023-12-21 15:48:05 -0800 Assertions            PID 521(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.wakeschedule" 00:00:05  id:0x0xd0000a258 [System: BGTask SRPrevSleep kCPU]
```

`pmset -g log | grep DarkWake`

```
2023-12-21 14:45:39 -0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNPB] : due to ATC1.USBWakeup smc.70070000 smc.70170000 USB2_plug/ Using AC (Charge:81%)           
2023-12-21 14:48:27 -0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNPB] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan/ Using AC (Charge:83%)           
2023-12-21 14:51:34 -0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNPB] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan/ Using AC (Charge:85%)           
2023-12-21 14:54:41 -0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNPB] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan/ Using AC (Charge:87%)           
2023-12-21 14:57:48 -0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNPB] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan/ Using AC (Charge:89%)           
2023-12-21 15:00:55 -0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNPB] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan/ Using AC (Charge:91%)           
2023-12-21 15:04:01 -0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNPB] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan/ Using AC (Charge:93%)           
2023-12-21 15:07:09 -0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNPB] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan/ Using AC (Charge:94%)           
2023-12-21 15:49:33 -0800 Wake                  DarkWake to FullWake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to HID Activity Using AC (Charge:100%)
```

`pmset -g log | grep "Wake Requests"`

```
2023-12-21 14:59:58 -0800 Wake Requests         [process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1009 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:16:48 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.6Hours"] [*process=dasd request=TimerPlugin deltaSecs=925 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:15:24 info="com.apple.dasd:502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photosanalysis"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7199 wakeAt=2023-12-21 16:59:57 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=CSPNEvaluation deltaSecs=4572 wakeAt=2023-12-21 16:16:11] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=2881 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:48:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-invisible-com.apple.calaccessd.travelEngine.periodicRefreshTimer,1134"]           
2023-12-21 15:03:05 -0800 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=926 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:18:31 info="com.apple.dasd:502:com.apple.chronod.nextScheduledTimelineRefresh"] [process=dasd request=TimerPlugin deltaSecs=1072 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:20:57 info="com.apple.dasd:502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photos.ocr"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7199 wakeAt=2023-12-21 17:03:04 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=CSPNEvaluation deltaSecs=4385 wakeAt=2023-12-21 16:16:11] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=2694 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:48:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-invisible-com.apple.calaccessd.travelEngine.periodicRefreshTimer,1134"]           
2023-12-21 15:06:11 -0800 Wake Requests         [process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1064 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:23:56 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.2Hours"] [*process=dasd request=TimerPlugin deltaSecs=988 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:22:40 info="com.apple.dasd:502:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photos.ocr"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2023-12-21 17:06:10 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=CSPNEvaluation deltaSecs=4199 wakeAt=2023-12-21 16:16:11] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=2508 wakeAt=2023-12-21 15:48:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-invisible-com.apple.calaccessd.travelEngine.periodicRefreshTimer,1134"]
```

Comment: do you have sharing enabled

Comment: @Ruskes all sharing options are disabled.

Comment: I do not know the answer without more information. For that pls run `pmset -g log | grep wake` in Terminal it will give you long list, but look at the time stamp when it supposed to sleep. Lets also look at the `darkwake`

Comment: Do you have a USB mouse attached?

Comment: @Ruskes Updated with pmset logs.

Comment: @benwiggy I have a USB keyboard, and a bt mouse. But I've seen the same behavior with everything disconnected.

Comment: You have few of the `2023-12-21 14:48:27 -0800 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDNPB] : due to SMC.OutboxNotEmpty smc.70070000 wifibt wlan/ Using AC (Charge:83%)`           
`Which is due to the Mail app has not send the emails ?

Comment: I've attempted to take the steps here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252061187?sortBy=best

And will watch to see what happens.